# the output is throwing large numbers

Tags: c++

the question is:
Chef has gone shopping with his 5-year old son. They have bought N items so far. The items are numbered from 1 to N, and the item i weighs Wi grams.

Chef's son insists on helping his father in carrying the items. He wants his dad to give him a few items. Chef does not want to burden his son. But he won't stop bothering him unless he is given a few items to carry. So Chef decides to give him some items. Obviously, Chef wants to give the kid less weight to carry.

However, his son is a smart kid. To avoid being given the bare minimum weight to carry, he suggests that the items are split into two groups, and one group contains exactly K items. Then Chef will carry the heavier group, and his son will carry the other group.

Help the Chef in deciding which items should the son take. Your task will be simple. Tell the Chef the maximum possible difference between the weight carried by him and the weight carried by the kid.Chef has gone shopping with his 5-year old son. They have bought N items so far. The items are numbered from 1 to N, and the item i weighs Wi grams.

Chef's son insists on helping his father in carrying the items. He wants his dad to give him a few items. Chef does not want to burden his son. But he won't stop bothering him unless he is given a few items to carry. So Chef decides to give him some items. Obviously, Chef wants to give the kid less weight to carry.

However, his son is a smart kid. To avoid being given the bare minimum weight to carry, he suggests that the items are split into two groups, and one group contains exactly K items. Then Chef will carry the heavier group, and his son will carry the other group.

Help the Chef in deciding which items should the son take. Your task will be simple. Tell the Chef the maximum possible difference between the weight carried by him and the weight carried by the kid.

Input:

The first line of input contains an integer T, denoting the number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. The first line of each test contains two space-separated integers N and K. The next line contains N space-separated integers W1, W2, ..., WN.

Output:

For each test case, output the maximum possible difference between the weights carried by both in grams.

Sample Input 1

2

5 2

8 4 5 2 10

8 3

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Sample Output 1

17

2

Explanation

Case #1: The optimal way is that Chef gives his son K=2 items with weights 2 and 4. Chef carries the rest of the items himself. Thus the difference is: (8+5+10) ? (4+2) = 23 ? 6 = 17.

Case #2: Chef gives his son 3 items and he carries 5 items himself.

my code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

int main() {
    int t=0,n=0,k=0,j=0;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        cin>>n>>k;
        int arr[n],son=0,father=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>arr[n];
        }
        sort(arr,arr+n);
        
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(j>=n-1-k){
                father+=arr[j];
            }
            else{
                son+=arr[j];
            }
        }
        cout<<father-son<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the ouput im getting is this:
1007357324

1389213724

Comment: Wherever you learned `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`, never go there again.

Comment: @Eljay i used that to sort the array

Comment: Sorting is in `#include <algorithm>`. Never never never include that bits thingumy.

Comment: Throwing large numbers. Geeze. I hope no one was hurt.

Comment: `int arr[n]` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value such as `n`.  Instead, use `std::vector<int> arr(n);`.  Thus given that the array is fake, this: `sort(arr,arr+n);` is also fake, as you are relying on fake C++ arrays to give you the desired result when you say `arr + n`.  As a matter of fact, early versions of a certain compiler that allowed the fake syntax would give syntax errors when those "arrays" were used in STL algorithm functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are getting bigger numbers because on this line

```cpp
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>arr[n];
}
```

You are changing the value on arr[n] (that doesn't exist because you array goes from 0 to n-1). Basically you are not changing any value inside the array so its using trash values that were stored on the memory.

The fix to not get those big number is change the line `cin>>arr[n];` to `cin>>arr[i];`. I didnt test your code to check if you will have a correct answer to the problem that you are trying to solve but the big numbers will go away.

Cheers!

Comment: im so ashamed of committing a crime like this. Thanksss